# Calling node.js from makefile fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, makefile

I have a simple hello world `js` file I run from terminal with `node`, and **everything works fine**. When I try to run the exact same thing from my `makefile` it prints the hello world part **but then fails**. Here is the relevant target from makefile:

```
run: ${JS_DIR}/main.js
    node ${JS_DIR}/main.js
```

And here is the error I get:

```
$ make run
node /some/dir/main.js
Hello World
makefile:44: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 254
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A make target will fail if any of its recipes return an error code (i.e., non-zero).  `node` is returning a non-zero.   Try running

```
node /some/dir/main.js; echo $?
```

to confirm.

You could either update main.js to not return an error (I believe this is done by calling `process.exit()` with no parameters or a `0` parameter, but I'm not a node or js expert, so take that with a grain of salt).

Alternatively, you could make make ignore the return code by adding a `-` to the beginning of the recipe:

```
run: ${JS_DIR}/main.js
    -node ${JS_DIR}/main.js
```

Comment: Indeed, the `echo $?` produced the same error code. Thanks.